# Not getting TCP Update Window packet after TCP Zero Window begins

Tags: sockets, tcp, nat

Once I get TCP Zero Window during data transmission, I can't send data anymore in that desktop sharing session. Even I stopped the data sending to check if it can resume but no benefit!

In my test environment, I sent 1 packet per 30 second after getting the zero window to check if zero window disappeared, ran the call more that 2 hour but no window update packet have been received.

[Wireshark TCP dump](https://drive.google.com/a/anyconnect.com/file/d/0B9S4kLE-dz6JQU1jRjR2a2xfeEE/view?usp=sharing).

FYI: I am working on Desktop application sharing between Lync for Mac and my library(Unix pc) over Wi-Fi network.

Comment: I can't access your TCP dump.  Your link to a Drive document needs to be set to "anyone with the link can view" or better.  Also, you talk about sending packets...  Are you writing your own TCP stack?  If not, you're only "writing data" (to the socket), not "sending packets".  There are no "packets" to users of TCP.

Comment: Extremely sorry about the link sharing privacy. Please take a look on the link again.

Comment: I just write the data on the socket rely on system to send the data. Isn't it the only way for transmission in tcp?

Comment: Is the peer ever reading from the connection to clear the zero window?